# jQuery UI Dialog Changes URL on Enter KeyPress

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, forms, jquery-ui

I'm trying to submit a form with AJAX, the form being content of jQuery UI Dialog.

I use the same code as in [jQuery's documentation](http://jqueryui.com/dialog/#modal-form)

but I modified the form so there is only one text input, so the form looks like this:

```
<form>
  <fieldset>
    <label for="answer"><strong>Your Answer : </strong></label>
    <input type="text" name="answer" id="answer" class="text ui-widget-content ui-corner-all" />    
  </fieldset>
  </form>
```

When I click the OK (or Create User) Button, it works, i.e. submits the answer with AJAX, but I also want it to work when pressed Enter key.

now, when I type `asd` in `input#answer` and press enter, it makes the URL like this:

```
mysite.com/?answer=asd
```

I tried adding the function:

```
  $('#answer').keypress(function(e) {
    if (e.keyCode == $.ui.keyCode.ENTER) {
          alert("enter pressed on answer input");
    }
});
```

this time it alerts `"enter pressed on answer input"` and then converts the URL. Whereas, I don't want it to modify the URL, how can I delete that function? Where is it defined?

In short, I want the enter key to do only what I want it to do.

Thanks for any help !

### Edit:

The buttons -that work on mouse click- are added in `jQuery.dialog();` like this:

```
$( "#dialog-form" ).dialog({
      autoOpen: false,
      height: 300,
      width: 350,
      modal: true,
      buttons: {
        Answer: function() {
            var answer = $("#dialog-form #answer").val();
            alert("your answer : "+answer);
                    submit_with_ajax(answer);
        },
        Cancel: function() {
          $( this ).dialog( "close" );
        }


      },
      close: function() {
        allFields.val( "" ).removeClass( "ui-state-error" );
        alert("asd");
      }
    });
```

Comment: Sounds like a bug. Maybe you can prevent default (`e.preventDefault()`) and fake a click on said button (`$('thingy').click()`).

Comment: Are you Using a Submit button ?? or without it???

Comment: @Sumurai8 Thanks! No need to fake the click, I can call a function on enter press. I will check out how to use preventDefault now. Or you can post it as the answer :)

Comment: @Gokul I'm adding buttons in jQuery code. I will add the code in my question now.

Comment: e.preventDefault() is Right, to prevent Submiting the form. or YOU CAN USE `<form onsubmit="return false">` to not to submit at all.

Comment: Or `<form action="javascript:void(0)">`. There are lots of ways to prevent the default submission.

Comment: oh, yes e.preventDefault works. I just didn't know it before :) Thanks for all the help. Again, Sumurai8 if you post it as an answer i will accept it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can prevent the default action of an event with `event.preventDefault()`. I am not 100% sure how the form looks like in jQuery-ui and if preventing the default of the keypress works. As an alternative you can prevent the default action of the `submit` event which, as you would probably expect, prevents the form from being submitted (as per Gokul's answer). See [mdn](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/event.preventDefault) for more information on `event.preventDefault()`.

```
$('#answer').keypress(function(e) {
    if (e.keyCode == $.ui.keyCode.ENTER) {
          e.preventDefault();
    }
});
```

-- or --

```
$('whatevertheuiformis').on( 'submit', function(e) {
    if (e.keyCode == $.ui.keyCode.ENTER) {
          e.preventDefault();
    }
});
```

Answer (score 2):

As yours...

```
<form>
<!-- <form onsubmit="return false"> is an optional -->
<fieldset>
    <label for="answer">
        <strong>Your Answer : </strong>
    </label>
    <input type="text" name="answer" id="answer" 
           class="text ui-widget-content ui-corner-all" />
</fieldset>
</form>
```

---

```
//jQuery Version
$('form').submit(function(){
    return false;
});
// javascript
document.getElementById('my-form').onsubmit = function() {
    return false;
}
$('#answer').keypress(function(e) {
    if (e.keyCode == $.ui.keyCode.ENTER) {
        e.preventDefault();
        //alert("enter pressed on answer input");
        submit_with_ajax(answer);
    }
});
```

So Here the Form will not submit at all.. so that you can perform your `AJAX` submission or REQUEST....

Hope it helps...

Comment: it definitely does. However, for some reason, I don't like to use html attributes, I want to handle all the things in JavaScript, for reusable code I guess :) If sumurai8 does not post his answer, I will accept yours.

Answer (score 1):

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/sarathsprakash/9mSwj/)**

Try this,

Enter the value in input answer and click enter

```
$(document).ready(function () {
     $(document).on('keypress',function(e)
               {
                if(e.which==13 && $("#answer").val().length>0)
                {
                    alert("hi"); // do your ajax call here
                }
          });
});
```

Hope this helps

Comment: It should, but in my case, the form is inside jQuery UI's modal dialog, not in plain HTML. Thanks anyway !